# virtual const function not returning initialised value

Tags: c++

I have a basic class and header set up relating to an animal, I am trying to have a function which displays an animals current hunger level. Upon testing i have found the hunger level is not at the initial value i have set.

Monkey.cpp

```
#include "Monkey.hpp"

using namespace std;

Monkey::Monkey() {
}

unsigned int foodEaten = 0;
unsigned int foodIntake = 800;

unsigned int Monkey::hungerLevel() const {
    return (makefoodIntake - foodEaten);    
}
```

Monkey.hpp

```
#ifndef MONKEY_HPP
#define MONKEY_HPP

class Monkey : public Animal {
private:
unsigned int foodEaten;
unsigned int foodIntake;

public:
Monkey();
// Overridden to implement the monkey's hunger level
virtual unsigned int hungerLevel() const;

#endif /* end of include guard: MONKEY_HPP */
```

Why does this not return 800 initially?

Comment: The variables in your .cpp file are global variables.

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow!!!

Comment: If you think it has anything to do with `virtual` and `const`, remove those two and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did not initialize the members of the class in your constructor.

You have some other variables, with the same name that are declared in the global scope.

However, because you have class members of the same name, the method uses the class members, and not the variables in the global scope.

You need to simply initialize the class members, instead of declaring global variables of the same name:

```
Monkey::Monkey() : foodEaten(0), foodIntake(800)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both, `foodEaten` and `foodIntake` defined in the `.cpp` file are two variables in the global scope and not members of the class `Monkey`.

Initialize them in the header file as well:

```
class Monkey {
  private:
    unsigned int foodEaten{0};
    unsigned int foodIntake{800};
// ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked however now i get an error, warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: The compiler tells you all there is to know.

Comment: Josh: In C++03 you would need to initialize the variables in a constructor. However, the real question is this: "Don't you actually want those variables to be members of the `Monkey` class, and not global?"